# Symbolic summation with variable bounds and variable number of indices

Tags: symbolic, summation, differentials, indexed-variable

I wish to compute compute terms like `Sum[f[t[j[1]],t[j[2]],...],{j[1],m},{j[2],n},...]` for arbitrary positive integer `n` and any number of indices `j[1],...,j[m]`. I also wish to able to do differentiations like `D[f,t[j[k]]]` and obtain the correct result.

It seems you cannot do the folowing:

```
f = Sum[1/(1 - x Exp[I (t[j[1]] - t[j[2]])]),Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{j[k], n}, {k, 2}]]]
t /: D[t[a_], t[b_], NonConstants -> {t}] := KroneckerDelta[a, b]
D[f, t[m], NonConstants -> t]
```

The kernel keeps running without simplifying the output.